# Двусмысленная метка [cli]

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, метки, описание-метки, создание-метки

**Проблема**

На ruSO есть такая метка, как [cli](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cli). Я недавно добавил к этой метке описание, но, как заметил [@insolor](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1365/insolor), чаще всего эта метка используется не как Common Language Infrastructure, а как Command Line Interface.

Лично я добавил описание к метке после [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1157355/%d0%92-%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-cli-%d0%b8-cls) вопроса, и в моей голове аббревиатура «CLI» означала именно Common Language Infrastructure, при этом, не глядя на остальные вопросы с этой меткой, я пошёл редактировать её описание.

Думаю, хватит путаницы с этой меткой!

**Предложение по решению**

- Создать метку [command-line-interface](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/command-line-interface)
- Сделать новосозданную метку синонимом метки [cli](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cli)
- Создать метку [common-language-infrastructure](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/common-language-infrastructure)
- Скопировать текущее описание метки [cli](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cli) в описание метки [common-language-infrastructure](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/common-language-infrastructure)
- Изменить описание метки [cli](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cli):

  - Стереть подробное описание
  - Изменить краткое описание на:

> Данная метка используется для старых вопросов по Command Line Interface. Т.к. данная аббревиатура многозначна, вместо данной метки использовать либо метку [command-line-interface], либо метку [common-language-infrastructure], в зависимости от вашего вопроса.

---

<sub>**ПРИМЕЧАНИЕ.** Т.к. это [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5), то можете вносить свои коррективы в это предложение по решению этой проблемы, если согласны, или отклонить его, в противном случае.</sub>

Comment: потом какой нибудь юзер все равно создаст метку `cli` :)

Comment: Метка common-language-infrastructure не нужна. Единственно, где cli употрябляется в этом контексте, это язык C++/CLI. И там путаницы нет.

Comment: А зачем нужна метка по `Command Line Interface`?

Comment: @nomnoms12 по ней есть вопросы, значит она нужна

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov но в вопросе, который я привёл в пример, эта метка ещё как нужна

Comment: @Barmaley жаль, что метку нельзя пометить как "устаревшую"

Comment: В том вопросе CLI - просто термин. Не на каждый термин, используйющийся в IT, следует создавать метку.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я считаю, что метка всё же нужна

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov давайте удалим тогда метку [1c], т.к. по ней аж 0 вопросов — 1С — просто термин, который не нужен

Comment: Термин - нужен. Метка - возможно, нет.

Comment: @return `по ней есть вопросы`, — это не показатель необходимости. Вы можете себе представить эксперта по интерфейсу командной строки?..

Comment: @nomnoms12, легко.

Comment: @Qwertiy Раз Вы так говорите, я сдаюсь :)

Comment: Одно из следствий законов Мерфи - если метку можно спутать - ее, вероятно, спутают... Если ее спутать нельзя - спутают обязательно.

Comment: *Данная метка используется для старых вопросов по Command Line Interface.* С какого перепугу старых-то? или уже командную строку запретили? А, скажем, в MySQL это вообще аббревиатура, которая используется в официальной документации как обозначение штатного клиента командной строки, да и совет проверить запрос в CLI - достаточно повседневный...

Comment: @Akina старые вопросы — вопросы до разделения метки на два.

Answer (score 7):

> Создать метку command-line-interface

У нас уже есть метка [командная-строка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0), которая обозначает то же самое. Кроме того, русскоязычные метки у нас предпочтительнее. Лучше перенести вопросы по интерфейсам командной строки в эту метку.

> Создать метку common-language-infrastructure

Слишком длинное название для понятия, которое в контексте сайта значит столь мало. Common Language Infrastructure - это стандарт ECMA-335, который описывает, упрощенно говоря, всю технологию .NET, кроме конкретных языков программирования. Для вопросов, касающихся ECMA-335, тематика достаточно хорошо описывается единственной меткой [.net](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net). Я бы сказал, или такая метка вообще не нужна, или она должна называться [ecma-335](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ecma-335).

Comment: про метку [tag:командная-строка] не знал, спасибо.

Comment: правильно я понимаю, ваш ответ про то, что всё нужно оставить как есть, только для вопросов по командной строке нужно метку [tag:cli] заменить на более подходящую метку [tag:командная-строка]?

Comment: @return Да, + возможно, создать синоним [cli] -> [командная-строка]. Такой синоним нужен, но он будет иметь неприятный эффект для C++/CLI...